# Reading text from several files C++

Tags: c++

I have some text files in a folder named foo1, foo2,...,foo5. I tried to write a C++ program 
to print out the contents of the files but the compiler is giving an error. 
Here is the program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  string common="foo";

  for(int count=1;count<=5;++count)
  {
  //Convert count to an string.
  stringstream ss;
  ss<<count;
  string numstring=ss.str();

  string filename=common+numstring;
  ifstream infile(filename); 
  string line;

  //Print out the lines from the file.
   while(getline(infile,line))
     {
       cout<<line<<endl;

     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler is giving an error like

```
g++ -Wall c++.cpp
c++.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
c++.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::string&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:454: note: candidates are: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:440: note:                 std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:81: note:                 std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
```

Can someone help me out with this? The output of the program should be what I would get if I typed `cat foo*` at the terminal.

Comment: <iostream>
<iomanip>
<fstream>
<sstream>
<cmath>
<cstdlib>
<string>
<list>
<vector>
<algorithm>
<stdexcept>

Comment: That works for me in VS2010. I don't have access to G++ atm sorry, but that seems very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
ifstream infile(filename);
```

with

```
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
```

The error message that you posted shows you this.  `fstream` is a typedef for `basic_fstream<>`. Your error message says, in essence, that there is no `fstream` constructor that takes a `string&`, but there is one that takes a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
ifstream infile(filename);
```

The `ifstream` class doesn't know how to take a string as a filename. I does know how to take a character array:

```
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
```

You should have worked this out with a single input file, before you introduced the iteration. **Start simple and build up. Test all the way. Never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: `std::ifstream` requires a c-style string up through C++03, but allows an `std::string` as of C++11 and current releases of many compilers already support this, though it looks like the OP is using g++ 4.4, which is old enough it probably doesn't (i.e., while you're answer isn't necessarily correct in general, it probably is for the OP).